# Following multiple log files efficiently

Tags: database, linux, logging

I'm intending to create a programme that can permanently follow a large dynamic set of log files to copy their entries over to a database for easier near-realtime statistics. The log files are written by diverse daemons and applications, but the format of them is known so they can be parsed. Some of the daemons write logs into one file per day, like Apache's cronolog that creates files like access.20100928. Those files appear with each new day and may disappear when they're gzipped away the next day.

The target platform is an Ubuntu Server, 64 bit.

What would be the best approach to efficiently reading those log files?

I could think of scripting languages like PHP that either open the files theirselves and read new data or use system tools like `tail -f` to follow the logs, or other runtimes like Mono. Bash shell scripts probably aren't so well suited for parsing the log lines and inserting them to a database server (MySQL), not to mention an easy configuration of my app.

If my programme will read the log files, I'd think it should stat() the file once in a second or so to get its size and open the file when it's grown. After reading the file (which should hopefully only return complete lines) it could call tell() to get the current position and next time directly seek() to the saved position to continue reading. (These are C function names, but actually I wouldn't want to do that in C. And Mono/.NET or PHP offer similar functions as well.)

Is that constant stat()ing of the files and subsequent opening and closing a problem? How would `tail -f` do that? Can I keep the files open and be notified about new data with something like select()? Or does it always return at the end of the file?

In case I'm blocked in some kind of select() or external tail, I'd need to interrupt that every 1, 2 minutes to scan for new or deleted files that shall (no longer) be followed. Resuming with tail -f then is probably not very reliable. That should work better with my own saved file positions.

Could I use some kind of inotify (file system notification) for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how `tail -f` works, why not look at [the source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c)?  In a nutshell, you don't need to periodically interrupt or constantly stat() to scan for changes to files or directories.  That's what inotify does.

Comment: I believe this question leads the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324258/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-net-filesystemwatcher-in-the-linux-world - and it looks like a good solution.