# Linux trigger after editing a file

Tags: linux, triggers, scheduler

Is it possible to create a trigger trigger's in Linux, that run if a software doses any changes in a particular file or folder.

Could you recommend be any tutorial that could help me in that.

Thanks

Comment: FAM - the file alteration monitor and similar tools can achieve that.

Comment: There are plenty of alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324258/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-net-filesystemwatcher-in-the-linux-world

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). You can use it with things like Perl's [Linux::Inotify2](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm). Or, whatever other hooks you want to put into it.

From the man page:

---

**Name**

*inotify - monitoring file system events*

**Description**

*The inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring file system events. Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to monitor directories. When a directory is monitored, inotify will return events for the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.*

Comment: I have been looking for you inotify thing but no progress in it.
I am unable to understand how to use it.
Anyways Thanks for your help friend.