# Keeping millions of thumbnails updated

Tags: image, sorting, filesystems, thumbnails

We have a massive collection of images (think 30+ million images).

The image files are quite big, so it's slow to work with the files in our application for sorting images etc.

We have therefore decided to make thumbnails of all the files (we have the necessary storage + processing power for generating the thumbnails).

Now the problem is that sometimes an image needs to be deleted or replaced with an updated image - and we do of course want the thumbnails to stay updated, so they are also deleted/replaced if images are deleted/replaced.

Do we really need to implement our own service/program/script for this - or can someone recommend an existing service/program/script that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using? I guess the clue would be to change whatever creates/deletes/updates the original images to schedule an update/deletion of the thumbnail - is that an option?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I *think* you're asking how to detect if an image is deleted, added, or updated, so that you can automatically update the thumbnail. If that's it, then what you use will depend on your OS and language. In .NET, you'd use a `FileSystemWatcher`. On Windows, look into the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function. On Linux, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/324258/56778.

Comment: It's not an option to schedule changes. The are several independent systems that maintain the image collection.

Comment: Good ideas Jim. I'll check out those options and see if they can scale performancewise to 30+ million images.

Comment: The number of images doesn't really matter. What matters is the frequency of updates.